# Adding a new keystore to artifactory breaks existing https connection

Tags: docker, ssl, artifactory, keystore, self-signed

We have a docker container running artifactory at my job and we need to add a custom keystore with the [self-signed certificates](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+a+Self-Signed+Certificate) to use Crowd authentication mechanism.

What we did was remove the old docker container and run a new one with the following launching argument :

```
-e EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/keystore/selfsignedcerts.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=selfsignedpassword"
```

This worked and we could use the crowd auth mechanism but it broke the npm-remote repository (https://registry.npmjs.org) (and other https repos too)

We get the following error when the launch argument is used trying to test the npm-remote repo :

> Connection to remote repository failed: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

My hypothesis is that using the argument overwrites the default keystore but i am unsure. Instead of replacing it, is there any ways to use two keystores at once or append the self-signed certificates to the existing one? (I can't even locate the keystore).

Answer (score 0):

We managed to find a solution with the following :

https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-resolve-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error/

Quick explain: We had to add out intermediate and root certificates to the regular cacerts file that comes with artifactory. We realized the best way to do this was through making a custom docker image based on artifactory :

```
Dockerfile :

FROM docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:<your version or latest>
COPY cacerts_with_your_intermediatesAndRoots /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

Then run this new image instead of the barebone artifactory and it'll work.

Note that if you currently have a custom image you should simply add the COPY line to your existing Dockerfile. Also, if you're not running artifactory using Docker, then just add your certificates to the file and restart.

You may also notice i'm using a different path than the one used in the link above. That's because their path is a symbolic link and not the actual file.

In case you have a question feel free to contact me.